# Get changes for an item or a file(properties only) time range

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

How do I get the Since to Until section to work?  I tried adding a 1 second and subtracting a 1 second but the error is the same.  If I leave Until blank it'll run, but it is not getting the correction version.

I was attempting to follow this article : https://sharepains.com/2020/09/24/changes-sharepoint-items-power-automate/
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to do a few seconds (addSec did not work unless you were precise on when the last version was), addDays did work though.  I found that the best way was to just subtract one version number.  Example below:

```
sub(int(items('Apply_to_each_2')?['{VersionNumber}']),1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it work with `addDays(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Created'],-1,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK')`. We need to identify the format in ISO8601 format. Or we can just use the version number.

It works also with `utcNow()`

Update for an example:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to get the Until section to work, can you show me your example?

Comment: @williswin, I updated the reply, please check.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense.. I'm also **getting the same error**. The only time it's working is when I'm using [created] or [Modified], by first getting the properties of the item by using ** [Get file properties]** action, and then using those fields as input for **Since** and **Until**.

I thought we could add/substract hours or minutes to/from [created] like

```
addHours(outputs('Get_file_properties')?['body/Created'],-4)
```

and then use it as input. But that's also **not** working.